# Remove sub-path of File name and create file structure

Tags: c#, file, directory, copy

I have following `List<String> fileNames` getting passed to my method,
I want to remove the sub-path from that and create the left out file structure

```
string subPath = "C:\\temp\\test"
List<string> filesIncoming = new List[]{@"C:\temp\test\a.txt", @"C:\temp\test\intest\a.txt"};
string outputDir = "C:\\temp3\\temp";
```

Output should be:

```
C:\\temp3\temp\a.txt
C:\\temp3\temp\intest\a.txt
```

This is what I am trying

```
foreach (var file in files)
{
    var directory = Path.GetDirectoryName(file);
    DirectoryInfo source = new DirectoryInfo(directory);

    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file);
    var destDir = Path.Combine(destinatonFilePath, source.Name); //how do I remove sub-path from source.Name and combine the paths properly?
    CreateDirectory(new DirectoryInfo(destDir));
    File.Copy(file, Path.Combine(destDir, fileName), true);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use the old good string.Replace to remove the common base path from your incoming files and replace it with the common base path for the output files

```
string subPath = "C:\\temp\\test"
string outputDir = "C:\\temp3\\temp";

foreach (var file in files)
{
    // Not sure how do you have named these two variables.
    string newFilePath = file.Replace(subPath, outputDir); 
    Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(newFilePath));
    File.Copy(file, newFilePath, true);
}
```